# Cannot find iPhone templates in XCode 3.x on Lion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I've an Intel mac machine with Lion installed on it. I've downloaded Xcode 3 from [here](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792) on it but when I start the Xcode I couldn't find any of iPhone project templates. I just found the Mac templates.

Comment: Paste a snapshot of your xcode first screen, you may have missed selecting the iphone app on the left bar.

Comment: No, I watched many videos that shows me where to find the templates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 3 ?? Have you tried downloading and installing xcode 4 ? Free in the mac app store ...

Also make sure you have downloaded and install the iOS SDK ...

Comment: I haven't enrolled in a payed dev program. And It needs me to.

Comment: To download the SDK ? You will need an account but you shouldn't have to pay just to get the SDK ...

Comment: Were you trying to download the SDK beta ? Think you need to be paid dev for that. 
Go back to developer.apple.com  then Resources > iOS Dev Center > Make sure youre on iOS SDk 4.3 NOT iOS SDK BETA! Then go to downloads and XCode 4. 

OR just go to the app store and download xcode from there .. that will include iOS SDK ...

Comment: Bear in mind that if you download it from the app store. That will just download an installer to your applications folder. You will then need to launch that installer, that will then install xcode 4 properly ...

Comment: Cannot download it directly... I usually faced that page https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ !! can you provide me a link for the download page?